# VS10 - C# - How can I add one specific .msi from another project to a ClickOnce deployment?

Tags: c#, clickonce, publish

I'm using Visual Studio 10. I have a solution containing several C# projects. One of them is a client winform application (Project A). I want to create a ClickOnce deployment from that project so that:
1) It behaves as a normal ClickOnce deployement, meaning each time a user clicks on the application shortcut icon, it checks if there's a new version and if so, it is reinstalled ---> I was able to do this.
2) It also reinstalls always (without checking for newer versions) an .msi file (the installation package of an application from another project (Project B) of the same solution) ---> I don't know how to achieve this. Ideally, I would like to include Project B .msi file in the Properties-Publish tag of project A (prerrequisites button?) but I couldn't find how. In this link: [Link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/3641b884-a826-4d47-9a97-052ae3a5e1ae/clickonce-deploy-files-from-other-project-in-a-solution?forum=winformssetup) they suggest to add the files as link (I understand it should be the .msi file in my case), but it didn't work for me (Project B application was not in the list of installed application and not the slightest reference to Project B in Project A's .application file)

I suspect I'll have to manually edit the manifest file of project A to include the .msi file from project B, something like

```
<PackageFiles>
    <PackageFile Name="ProjectB.msi"/>
</PackageFiles>
```

as it is suggested in this other link: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee335701(v=vs.100).aspx)

but I don't know if that makes sense and what the syntax would be in my case.

Any help regarding this issue will be highly appreciated.